# PHPmailer, sending from localhost using Gmail SMTP

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am trying to send mail using PHPmailer from localhost with Gmail SMTP. It doesn´t work. Sometimes i get email that google has blocked somebody trying to login into my account. Sometimes not. But email doesn´t get sent.

My code:

```
require("include/gmail-smtp.php");
                try{

                $mail->From = 'xxx@gmail.com';
                $mail->FromName = 'xxx';
                $mail->addAddress($email, $username);
                $mail->addReplyTo('xxx@gmail.com', 'xxx');
                $mail->WordWrap = 50;
                $mail->isHTML(true);
                $mail->Subject = 'Using PHPMailer';
                $mail->Body    = 'Hi Iam using PHPMailer library to sent SMTP mail from localhost';
                $mail->send();


                echo 'Message has been sent';
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo "There was an error, please try again later. <br>";
                echo $e;
            }
```

Here is gmail-smtp.php

```
    <?php 
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->host="ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->port=465;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'xxx@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'xxx';
?>
```

Comment: try `$mailer->SMTPDebug = 2;`  before sending your mail!

Comment: @undone now i got this error: 2014-09-13 11:40:49 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061) 2014-09-13 11:40:49 SMTP connect() failed.

Comment: try this: `$mail->Host= "smtp.gmail.com";$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";`

Comment: @undone got the same error

Comment: Can you access your GMail using email client like Thunderbird?

Comment: Thunderbird says: "Configuration could not be verified, the password and the host name correctly?"

Comment: Setup new mail account in Thunderbird using [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbird-and-gmail)

Comment: When i created new Gmail account Thunderbird connected to it, but PHP script still gives me the same error.

Comment: Check your firewall, It seems request is being blocked by your computer! (if using Apache: check if httpd has proper access to the network)

Comment: Gmail should use tls on port 587 - see the gmail example in PHPMailer gmail docs. Don't use SSL/465.

Comment: @esynchro even with port 587 it doesn´t work. Now i got this error: "SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)
SMTP connect() failed."

Comment: Did you check your firewall?

Comment: I have turned Firewall completely off, got the same error as before.

Comment: can you check your code on live server?